# Python beginner - trying to output using sys.stdout.write with print list

Tags: python, stdout

What I am looking to do is output the contents of the print list as above at the end of the `sys.stdout.write` just after the `ScriptRes:OK:`
**My code**

```
print list[0]['VersionString']
sys.stdout.write("ScriptRes:OK:")
```

I am sure this is probably easy to do but my googling is drawing blanks!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name as it will override the built in type.

Comment: But he's accessing it with index [0], and I'm assuming item 0 is a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is hard to understand, but it sounds like you want the result of the first print right after OK:.

No idea why you mix print and sys.stdout.write (which, as a beginner, you should probably not do unless you know why).

So one obvious way is `print "ScriptRes:OK:", list[0]['VersionString']`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a dictionary inside a list ,try this

sys.stdout.write('ScriptRes:OK:%s' %list[0]['VersionString'])